# How to detect a middle click on a div in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppouse we have this template:

```
<div class="myClass" (click)="doSomething($event)">
```

soSomething is not called on a middle click.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
<div class="myClass" (click)="$event.which == 2 ? doSomething($event) : null">
```

See also [Triggering onclick event using middle click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click)

**update 2/2018**

When I posted above answer I was working on a Linux machine and it worked for me.

Now I'm on a Mac and I'm not able to get a click event for anything else than the left mouse button.

You can try it yourself using

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tab3gb)

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons

Comment: I believe it will work on <a> element but unfortunately it doesn't work on <div>.

Comment: Works fine for me. Click on `XXX` and check the browser console https://plnkr.co/edit/SEa19jY14ZkQT5HL7bDJ?p=preview

Comment: Confirmed - it's working on the Plunkr provided. I'm using and older version of ng2 and that could be causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Makla thanks for the hint. I moved from Linux to Mac and here this approach doesn't work. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20155501/217408 for more details. https://plnkr.co/edit/lzlIHeR0mhbWSTLgTGRj?p=preview

Comment: @BenTaliadoros What browsers did you try?

Comment: I tried in chrome latest, didn't seem to work for me

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm also not able to get a middle click on my Mac.

Comment: Anyone trying this now should try using the event (mouseup) rather than (click).

Answer (score 23):

I solved this problem by using a small custom `middleclick` directive which is listening to the `mouseup` event because in my example (on macOS) the `click` HostListener is not fired on a middle click.

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[middleclick]' })
export class MiddleclickDirective  {
  @Output('middleclick') middleclick = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  middleclickEvent(event) {
    if (event.which === 2) {
      this.middleclick.emit(event);
    }
  }
}
```

With this you can use something like

```
<button (middleclick)="doSomething()">Do something</button>
```

Comment: Good solution thank you. But `which` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which). Use `event.button === 1` for detect middle [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button).

Comment: How do you even middle click on a mac?

Comment: With a Logitech MX Master 3 for example ;)