# new tabs opened with the scroll wheel of a mouse do not have a window.opener object

Tags: javascript, html

If I use the left mouse button to click on an anchor tag with a target of `_blank` `window.opener` is defined. If I use the scroll wheel to click on that same anchor tag, however, `window.opener` is not defined.

The issue is reproducable in Google Chrome and Firefox, on Windows 10 and Mac OS X and idk what to do about it.

Is there a way, in Javascript, I could disable scroll wheel clicking for select links? Maybe I could hook into a scroll wheel click event and make it behave as a left mouse click instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, UX-wise. If I'm on a site, and I try to middle-click a link and it doesn't work, I'm leaving the site, much as I do when sites override the context menu. That's my opinion though (hence a comment), so take it with the requisite amount of salt :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can emulate this behavior by checking [`event.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 // detecting that it was a wheel click on a link
 if (
  e.button === 1 &&
  e.target.tagName === 'A'
 ) {
   window.open(event.target.href);
   e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

However, this solution won't work if you are opening a link from another domain.

Comment: I had to borrow from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155501/569976 some to get this working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!